# mongodb - concept of batches

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Node.js and have got stuck at a particular scenario.

Let's say I have a document store called `samples` which I use to collect some time stamps from the client machine.

I want to introduce the concept of ***batches***

More precisely, I want to keep inserting into an existing document until the number of ***samples*** reaches a threshold, after which I would like to create a new document.

I can continue inserting and update number of samples to same document as follows

```
db.timestamps.update(
        {"guid": guid},
        {
            $inc: { samples: 1},
            $push: { timings: { clientTime: clientTime } }
        },
        { upsert: true }
    );
```

How can I add a check to stop inserting and create a new document once my ***sample count*** reaches say 300 for this example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if you can do this without two queries but you could try

```
db.col.update({
    guid:guid, samples: {$lt:300}
},
{
    $inc: { samples: 1},
    $push: { timings: { clientTime: clientTime } }
},
{
    upsert: true
})
```

That should insert a new document every 300 batches of the format:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51e518ad8d065caa3b208661"), "guid" : 10, "samples" : 1, "timings" : [  {  "clientTime" : 1 } ] }
```

Comment: I am getting the `Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers` error with the above code. Tried googling around but haven't been able to find anything constructive

Comment: @dopplesoldner I take back what I said, the documentation said not to use $inc with upsert but it seems to work me, I will modify query

Comment: @dopplesoldner After some testing that query should work, it is the same as what you had but with an added clause